# Array Formula Option for JOIN(", ", SORT... function reorganizing comma separated values alphabetically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create an array formula in Google Sheets that will take the contents of column G (all words separated by commas) and reorganize them alphabetically in the respective row in column H. However, researching this a bit, it seems array formulas do not work for JOIN. I need this to be an array formula because new blank rows are entered with external form submissions so I can't just copy a formula down row H.

Here is my formula and you can see in the screenshot how it's supposed to work. I can get it to work just for G2, but not for the whole column:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ",SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(G2:G,",")))))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwcDO.png)

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(G2:G,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",sort(tocol(index(trim(split(Σ,",")))))))))
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks. From what I've seen, I love this MAP function and would love to learn how to use it more. I really appreciate it!